# Trouble setting value for property in new View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, properties

I have an array of images `imageFilesArray` that are being used in a collection view in the first view controller `CaptureVC`. Then I created a second view controller `CreateVideoVC`. The second view controller will use the array of images for a video. I created a property in the `CreateVideoVC` called `NSArray *imagesArrayForVideo` and synthesized it. But I can not seem to figure out how to get the new `imagesArrayForVideo` to contain the same as `imageFilesArray`. Any help on how to correct this would be appreciated.

From `CaptureVC.m`

```
-(void)createVideo:(id)sender{

    CreateVideoVC *newVideo = [CreateVideoVC new];
    //Set imagesFilesArray equal to new Array Property
    NSLog(@"Start of CreateVideo Log: \n%@",imageFilesArray); //check to see if array is filled which it is

    imageFilesArray = newVideo.imagesArrayForVideo;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newVideo animated:YES];

}
```

`CreateVideoVC.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    anArrayForImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.imagesArrayForVideo];
    NSLog(@" Log for stupid thing %@", anArrayForImages);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variables' assignments are reversed.

You have determined that `imageFilesArray` contains a series of images. You want to persist this data cross-view controller to the CreateVideoVC. You are assigning a populated array the value of `newVideo.imagesArrayForVideo` (which is probably nil).

```
imageFilesArray = newVideo.imagesArrayForVideo;
```

becomes

```
newVideo.imagesArrayForVideo = imageFilesArray;
```

Comment: Thank you for that, it did the trick! I didn't realize i had them reversed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! Indicate it was the correct answer otherwise the site may think you are still seeking help.